# Modifying an array of quaternions

Tags: unity

I have written the following function to inter-change 2 specific elements of an array of quaternions:

```
private void ChangeRotations(Quaternion[] rotationsArray)
{
    Quaternion bone1Rot = rotationsArray [(int)Bone1ID];
    Quaternion bone2Rot = rotationsArray [(int)Bone2ID];

    Quaternion temp = bone1Rot;
    bone1Rot = bone2Rot;
    bone2Rot = temp;
}
```

But when I use `Debug.Log` to see if this has taken effect, I realize that the 2 array elements are unchanged.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with `rotationsArray`, you are just swapping the values in `bone1Rot` and `bone2Rot` around.

You need to actually modify the array, something like:

```
private void ChangeRotations(Quaternion[] rotationsArray)
{
    Quaternion temp = rotationsArray [(int)Bone1ID];
    rotationsArray [(int)Bone1ID] = rotationsArray [(int)Bone2ID];
    rotationsArray [(int)Bone2ID] = temp;
}
```